# My items not appearing in center and nor inline

Tags: html, css

My items are not appearing in center and not displaying inline. Any help.

My code is here:

```css
.top-nav {
    background-color: #505050;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar top-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="top-nav-items">
                <a href="#" title="home">Foodtruck</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-nav-items">
                <a href="#" title="home">Stores</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-nav-items">
                <a href="#" title="home">Customer Service</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To center the text, you can use `text-align: center;`. To make the text inline, you can use a `div` instead of a list.

```css
.top-nav {
    background-color: #505050;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
    <a href="#" title="home">Foodtruck</a>
    <a href="#" title="home">Stores</a>
    <a href="#" title="home">Customer Service</a>
</div>
```

And with a bit of styling:

```css
.top-nav {
    background-color: #505050;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
}

.each_link {
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
    <a class="each_link" href="#" title="home">Foodtruck</a>
    <a class="each_link" href="#" title="home">Stores</a>
    <a class="each_link" href="#" title="home">Customer Service</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @HaroonAhmed if you like my answer please, upvote and click the green check mark

Answer (score -1):

You can use display "flex" property to centre align the items. Also to make the "list" items horizontally you have to specify "display" property of the "li" list items.

```
.top-nav {
    display: flex;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```